# Why is Apache2 failing?

Tags: apache

I have issues with the server constantly. It seems to fail every few hours and I cannot tell why.

This morning I had 503 on all of my websites, I tried to restart Apache but

```
# service apache2 restart
[....] Restarting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use:     make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
failed!
```

I found out some of processes were still running. Killing them helped to restart Apache.

```
# grep -ri listen /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:#   supposed to determine listening ports     for incoming connections, and which
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# Include list of ports to listen on and     which to use for name based vhosts
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:#Listen 127.0.0.1:443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:#    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:#    Listen 443

# killall -9 apache2

# service apache2 restart
[ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2.
```

I still have no idea how to prevent it from failing, here are some logs that I totally don't understand. Please help :)

From the time when it failed:

```
[Sun May 31 06:26:00 2015] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 9466)
[Sun May 31 06:26:00 2015] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.2+', found '2.7.3'.
[Sun May 31 06:26:00 2015] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Sun May 31 06:26:00 2015] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
[Sun May 31 06:26:00 2015] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 1000 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Sun May 31 06:26:00 2015] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Sun May 31 06:26:01 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.8 PHP/5.5.25-1~dotdeb+7.1 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.3 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_wsgi/3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 31 06:26:01 2015] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 17083)
[Sun May 31 06:26:01 2015] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 17328)
[Sun May 31 06:26:01 2015] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 17329)
[Sun May 31 06:26:01 2015] [warn] long lost child came home! (pid 17330)
```

And this is logged basically constantly:

```
[Sun May 31 13:36:03 2015] [warn] Couldn't set uid/gid/priority, closing connection.
[Sun May 31 13:36:03 2015] [warn] (itkmpm: pid=30911 uid=1001, gid=1001) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(1005): Operation not permitted
[Sun May 31 13:36:03 2015] [warn] Couldn't set uid/gid/priority, closing connection.
[Sun May 31 13:36:03 2015] [warn] (itkmpm: pid=30897 uid=1001, gid=1001) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(1005): Operation not permitted
[Sun May 31 13:36:03 2015] [warn] Couldn't set uid/gid/priority, closing connection.
[Sun May 31 13:36:04 2015] [warn] (itkmpm: pid=30930 uid=1001, gid=1001) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(33): Operation not permitted
[Sun May 31 13:36:04 2015] [warn] Couldn't set uid/gid/priority, closing connection.
[Sun May 31 13:36:06 2015] [warn] (itkmpm: pid=30938 uid=1001, gid=1001) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(33): Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You should state this question on server fault. They may help you better. I guess its a uid/gid related problem. Did you update anything lateley?

Comment: What is server fault? Is it part of StackOverflow? Server was put together from scratch lately but I didn't do it. I believe all software was updated to latest.

Comment: ServerFault is one of the StackExchange sites. ServerFault ist for server administration, as StackOverflow is for programming stuff. Just click above on the StackExchange button and select server fault, you can login with you stackexchange account if you have one and dont need to create a new one,

Comment: Take a look at the bottom (footer) of this page and explore all the sites. ServerFault is on the left column, second from the top.